# How to customize social_stream gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-stream

I have successfully implemented social_stream but I am not able to incorporate its features in my app.I am not able to understand what is on github. Anyone who has implemented Social_Stream, plz help me with that. I want to change the look and feel of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Social Stream's wiki provides details on how to customize the application. Take a look at https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/How-to-change-controllers%2C-models%2C-views%2C-assets-and-locales

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the way [rails engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) work.

Here is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines) you should watch for customising an engine. (The exact same way you would do with social_stream)